# Multiple facebook share/like buttons for thumbnail images dynamically in website

Tags: jquery, facebook, html, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I am designing a photography website using HTML5, CSS3 and Jquery. In the gallery section of my website i need to list all images from database in thumbnail format with facebook share/like buttons for each image. I know how to add fb share/like buttons statically in html page, but how to create dynamic fb share/like buttons for each image fetched from DB on the go?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you not to store images in database but to store their link, for every image on fb we have different size, you can explore more using Graph API Explorer @developes section of FB for ex:

For Bigger Image(600 X 600): [Image 1](https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/t31.0-8/p600x600/10285172_10203648395030546_3023158534343132978_o.jpg)

For Smaller Image: [Image 2](https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/t31.0-8/p600x600/10285172_10203648395030546_3023158534343132978_o.jpg)

Both above are result of `GET` query, you will find it a lot easy to play with.
Similarly if you want to like a pic or story using Graph API Explorer you have to issue a `POST` query, following is a example of liking a status using it

```
10203695660372150/likes
```

where 10203695660372150 is object_id for my status. You can connect to fb using this 
[example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0) and to like or share use this [example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/)